# Google spreadsheets - find all hidden rows - only include rows that are not hidden

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code provided copies data from sheet "Feuille 3" to an another sheet named "INITIALE".  Some of the rows in the source sheet tab, "Feuille 3" are hidden.

I hide some rows in "Feuille 3" when col D has a checkbox with a "true" value.

I don't know how I can check the rows hidden in "Feuille 3" and remove these rows in my array "Nouvelleliste."

Here is the code :

```
function copiertableau() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var orig = ss.getSheetByName("Feuille 3");
  var dest = ss.getSheetByName("INITIALE");
  var Ancienneliste = orig.getDataRange().getValues();
  var Nouvelleliste = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < Ancienneliste.length; i++) {
    var Nouvelleligne = new Array(); 
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      Nouvelleligne[j] = Ancienneliste[i][j];
    }
    Nouvelleliste[i] = Nouvelleligne;
  }
  ss.getSheetByName("INITIALE").getRange(22, 1, Nouvelleliste.length, 3).setValues(Nouvelleliste);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Comment: I don't think checking if a row/column is hidden is currently possible with the API

Comment: There is currently an open feature request for a way to determine if a row is hidden.  [Link to feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36752184)

Answer (score 3):

The Advanced Sheets API has a way of finding all the rows that were hidden by the user or by code.  You must explicitly enable the Advanced Sheets API from the code editor.  From the code editor choose, "Resources" and "Advanced Google Services."  Scroll down to "Google Sheets API"  Turn the button ON.  Then click the link to Google API Console.  Enable the Google Sheets API in your console.

First get all the rows that are hidden.  In the example below, that is done in a separate function.  Then compare the current row index to the values in the array.  If there is a hidden row, then don't put the row's data into the array.

```
function copiertableau() {
  var arrOfHiddenRows,Nouvelleligne,o,sourceSheetTab,ss;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  sourceSheetTab = ss.getSheetByName("Feuille 3");
  var dest = ss.getSheetByName("INITIALE");

  sourceSheetTab = ss.getSheetByName("INITIALE");

  var Ancienneliste = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var Nouvelleliste = [];

  o = {};//Object for arguments to pass to function to get the hidden rows

  o.L = sourceSheetTab.getLastRow();
  o.ssID = ss.getId();//Put the spreadsheet file ID into the object with key name ssID
  o.sheetId = sourceSheetTab.getSheetId();

  arrOfHiddenRows = getRowsHiddenByUsr(o);//Get a list of all hidden rows in sheet tab sourceSheet
  //Logger.log('arrOfHiddenRows: ' + arrOfHiddenRows)

  for (var i = 0; i < Ancienneliste.length; i++) {
    if (arrOfHiddenRows.indexOf(i+1) !== -1) {//This row is hidden in the sheet sourceSheet
      continue;//continue to loop without putting this rows data into the array
    }

    Nouvelleligne = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      Nouvelleligne[j] = Ancienneliste[i][j];
    }


    Nouvelleliste[i] = Nouvelleligne;
  }

  ss.getSheetByName("INITIALE").getRange(22, 1, Nouvelleliste.length, 3).setValues(Nouvelleliste);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}

function getRowsHiddenByUsr(po) {
try{
  var arrHiddenRows,data,fields,i,j,L,L_sh,rows,sheets,sheetId,spreadsheetId,thisSheet,thisShID;

  /*
    po.L - row length of the sheet tab
    po.ssID - the spreadsheet file ID of the spreadsheet
    po.sheetID - The ID of the sheet tab
  */

  L = po.L;
  spreadsheetId = po.ssID;
  sheetId = po.sheetID;

  //Logger.log(L)
  //Logger.log('sheetId: ' + sheetId)

  arrHiddenRows = [];

  fields = "sheets(data(rowMetadata(hiddenByUser)),properties/sheetId)";//Get only metadata of hidden rows by user
  sheets = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, {fields: fields}).sheets;  
  L_sh = sheets.length;

  //Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId)
  //Logger.log('sheets.length: ' + sheets.length)

  for (i = 0; i < L_sh; i++) {
    thisSheet = sheets[i];

    //Logger.log('thisSheet === undefined: ' + thisSheet === undefined)

    if (thisSheet === undefined) {
      continue;
    }

    thisShID = thisSheet.properties.sheetId;
    //Logger.log('thisShID: ' + thisShID)

    if (thisShID === sheetId) {
      //Logger.log('they are equal')

      data = thisSheet.data;
      rows = data[0].rowMetadata;

      //Logger.log('thisShID: ' + thisShID)
      //Logger.log('rows.length: ' + rows.length)

      for (j = 0; j < L; j++) {
        //Logger.log(rows[j].hiddenByUser)
        if (rows[j].hiddenByUser) arrHiddenRows.push(j+1);
      }
    }
  }

  return arrHiddenRows;
}catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
  console.log(e.stack);//log the stack

}
}
```

Comment: Great solution. I could study from your answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you to the contributors of the blog post at the following link:  [GSuite Developers Blog - Using Google Sheets filters in Add-ons with Google Apps Script](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/using-google-sheets-filters-in-add-ons.html)

Answer (score 0):

thanks @SandyGood  It seems it's missing something.
Firstly, i changed

> var Ancienneliste = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

to put "sourceSheetTab" variable; and i delete a line because you put twice "sourceSheetTab" with 2 contents so i keep the first one.
Secondly, your function continue to copy hidden rows in the sourcesheet table.
maybe i can put my other code i did to hide rows in "Feuille 3" to help?

```
//global variables
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Feuille 3");

    function cacherRow() {
      for (var i=1; i < 300; i ++){
      var nb = sheet.getRange('D'+i).getValue();
      if (nb == true){
        sheet.hideRows(i);
      }
    }
    }
```

i enable googlesheets API in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script now offers a new method - [isRowHiddenByUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#isrowhiddenbyfilterrowposition) - to determine if a particular row is hidden or not.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < Ancienneliste.length; i++) {
    if (sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(i+1)) {
      // do something
    } 
  }
```

Note that you need to specify the row position in the method and it begins from 1, not 0.